# Grails - Startup Memory/Memory Usage/Domain objects

Tags: mysql, memory, grails, grails-orm

I deployed a Grails application that I built (first application I've made) that starts up with a memory usage of roughly 2 GB. (Tomcat 6)

The application maintains roughly 133,000 domain objects between 4 types. Most transactions to the DB are searches through about 115,000 of those objects and normal CRUD operations/file import and export.

After much usage, I see that my memory stamp is 3.3 GB.

First off - Why is the memory usage so high at start up? Does Grails by default cache domain object usage in memory?

Second - I've handled GORM cleanup at numerous points in the application, but the memory usage is still high (3.3GB). Is there something in the ORM layer that causes caching of transactions, etc?

Thanks

---

---------------**Edit**--------------------

Test: I removed all domain objects from the database

Startup: 514 MB

With objects: 993 MB (I trimmed some performance based on the DataSource file)

---

** Data Source **

```
dataSource {
pooled = true
driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
username = "xxx"
password = "xxx"
}
hibernate {
cache.use_second_level_cache = false
cache.use_query_cache = true
cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}
// environment specific settings
environments {
development {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update"
        url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb"
    }
}
test {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update"
        url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb"
    }
}
production {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update"
        url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: So your domain objects are on average 3.7 KB? That's ahem, a lot.

Comment: The objects contain a lot of data (115,000 of those objects have roughly 17 properties each). It may be a design issue, but I can't see a way to extract domain specific properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JVM options:
`-server -Xms512m -Xmx1048M -XX:MaxPermSize=1048m -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit`

*JavaMelody* and *perf4j*:
-to help you see where/what/how is your memory usage

See this http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=73
and this http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Memory-leak-td1358871.html
and this http://www.componentix.com/blog/8/run-long-batch-processing-jobs-in-grails-without-memory-leaks

Answer (score 2):

Grails is a memory hog.

Are you using hsqldb or a mysql backend database?

if you are using the default hsqlbd my guess is that its the Hsqldb default settings that are causing the problem.

my suggest would be to add this to your DataSource.groovy

```
url = "jdbc:hsqldb:file:" + location + "/prodDb_v02;hsqldb.default_table_type=cached;shutdown=true"
```

the first part jdbc:hsqldb:file:..... just sets the location for the database

the important part is hsqldb.default_table_type=cached;

this changes the default type from memory to cached.

Good write up on this here...

http://www.jroller.com/alessiopace/entry/hsqldb_memory_and_cached_tables

Comment: Using MySql. I will throw up my DataSource file contents. Reading that link now, just incase something will be useful (even if it's HSQL).

Comment: so I haven't done anything with MySql and grails..But having worked with large domain tables. I thinking something is still living in memory.

Comment: my suggest would be to use java visual vm and monitor the memory footprint of the app to see where it spikes

Comment: Thank you Nate - I'll download that and see what's up. I'm inclined to also think that something (like my objects) are being stored in memory.

Comment: You also have the 2nd level cache enabled which is going to use memory.  As was stated, Grails (well, really Hibernate more than anything) uses quite a bit of memory.  RAM is cheap.

Comment: Are you loading something data in your BootStrap ?

Answer (score 2):

Your using second level cache **and** query cache so that would explain some of your memory usage.

Beyond that it's hard to blindly guess why your using so much memory.  It could be a number of things so, before you start flipping switches and trail-by-fire testing I would recommend using something like [JavaMelody](http://grails.org/plugin/grails-melody) or [Ehcache monitor](http://ehcache.org/documentation/operations/monitor). This will help you understand what is going on behind the curtains and the impacts of the changes your making.

Grails does consume a *little* more memory than some comparable frameworks but performance problems like these are usually caused by the code base **and** configuration.  Also, you might want to take a look [here](http://memo.feedlr.com/?p=31) at some JVM options that might help.

Good luck.

Comment: "Grails does consume a little more memory than some comparable frameworks", define "comparable frameworks" please. I did some comparison of resources consumptions between Rails, Django and Grails, Grails consume almost 10x more memory then the others for a blank page...